# How to create my specific MySQL select?

Tags: mysql, select

I have 2 DB tables

Table1

```
[US_name1 : US]
[US_name2 : US]
[US_name3 : US]
[UK_name1 : UK]
[UK_name2 : UK]
[DE_name1 : DE]
[DE_name2 : DE]
```

...

and the Table2

...

```
[2014-05-01 : US_name1 : 150]
[2014-05-01 : US_name2 : 300]
[2014-05-01 : US_name3 : 12.2]
[2014-05-01 : UK_name1 : 18]
[2014-05-01 : UK_name2 : 24]
```

...

how can I get result from specific date (for example: all from 2014-04-30) in next data-format:

```
{[US] -> [name]=US_name1, [last]=150, [2014-05-01]=150, [2014-04-30]=103}
{[US] -> [name]=US_name2, [last]=300, [2014-05-01]=300, [2014-04-30]=786}
{[UK] -> [name]=UK_name1, [last]=18,  [2014-05-01]=18,  [2014-04-30]=362}
```

my query is incorrect:

```
SELECT t1.Country, t1.Name, t2.Date, t2.Name, t2.Value FROM t1, t2 WHERE t2.Date >='".$start."' ORDER BY `Date` DESC
    if($res){
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                if(!isset($rez[$row['Name']]['last'])){$rez[$row['Name']]['last']=$row['Value'];}
                if(!isset($rez[$row['Name']]['country'])){$rez[$row['Name']]['country']=$row['Country'];}
                $rez[$row['Name']][$row['Date']]=$row['Value'];
            }
        }
```

Comment: I assume you're not really trying to execute your SQL query directly in php, right?

Comment: i use mysql_query("select..."); of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a condition in your query to relate the two tables:

```
SELECT t1.Country, t1.Name, t2.Date as Date, t2.Name, t2.Value FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.Name LIKE t2.Name AND t2.Date >='".$start."' ORDER BY `Date` DESC
```

Note you can't order by `Date` unless you alias `t2.Date` as `Date`, so I fixed that too.

Comment: Hmm... It's working! Than You, friend! (i can't vote because have not needed reputation)

Comment: Go ahead and check this answer as answered.  Thanks!

Comment: How can i mark it answered? I don't see any button or links for this

Comment: Should be a check mark below the up/down vote arrows